# Poor write performance with HP ProLiant ML 150 Gen9

Tags: hp-proliant, windows-server-2019

Transferring large files from one drive (USB or SATA to RAID) in my *HP ProLiant ML150 Gen9* is slow. At the beginning we were thinking about the B140i controller - a pseudo-raid controller without any memory cache.

This is the original B140i performance and the improvement after upgrading to smart array p440/4gbFWC.

[image: B140i PERFORMANCE]
[image: P440-4G PERFORMANCE]

Raid configuration is RAID 10 with 4 x SSD 500GB drives on both cases.

Although improved, the problem was still present: **When transferring large files, speed drops dramatically after a couple of minutes, from 400 MB /S and remains at 6-7 MB/s till the end of the transfer:**
[image: SPEED DROP]

I tried without success:

- Clean install of Windows 2012R2
- Clean install of Windows 2019
- Upgraded all firmware and drivers of using the latest *ProLiant Service Pack*

---

This is perfomance while copying a file from P440/4GB volume to the same volume:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJR6A.jpg)

Now machine is running 3 VM with only 18% of free memory. Older tests was done without any VM running.

Comment: Please add details about your server hardware and raid config/layout

Comment: Any antivirus scanning on access ?

Comment: No antivirus on windows 2012r2 and disabled on windows 2019.

Comment: raid 10 configuration over 4 ssd 500 gb hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I set the B140 to AHCI and I connected a low end SSD to its SATA port.

Look at this:

This is the behaviour when try to copy 76GB file from a USB 3.0 SSD to the SSD connected to the AHCI B140i:

[image: USB3.0 to B140i ahci mode]

This one is when I copy the file from B140i AHCI MODE to P440/4GB RAID 10:

[image: b140I TO P440/4GB]

The only way to get the full performance transfer is to use non-RAID drives. Any other option has an annoying drop of speed. It doesn't matter which direction:

1. from USB3.0 to P440/4GB RAID --> SPEED DROP.
2. from P440/4GB to USB3.0 --> SPEED DROP.
3. from USB3.0 to B140i RAID MODE --> SPEED DROP.
4. from B140I (AHCI or RAID) to P440/4GB --> SPEED DROP.

**5. from USB3.0 to B140i AHCI --> SUCCESFUL PERFORMANCE.**

Answer (score 0):

In HP Smart Storage Administrator: Active Writing Cache on the drive

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're seeing on write - fast at first and then breaking in - is Windows's write cache. It fills available memory (fast) and when that's exhausted you see the real hardware speed.

RAID controllers without cache suck at writing, especially the HPE ones. On-board (host) RAID is really bad but low-end E-type controllers aren't really that much better.

Either switch the controller to AHCI and build your RAID in Windows or - much better - get a decent *P*-type RAID controller with cache and battery module (the battery is required/recommended to activate write-behind caching).